# obtaining named attributes of self

Tags: python

according to my understanding of concatenation this code should work:

```
aList = ["first", "second", "last"]
for i in aList:
    print self.i
```

My class defines the bindings `self.first=something` as well as `self.second` and `self.last`. When I write `print self.first` the code works but `print self.i` raises an exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I edited the question as it was somewhat ambiguous as stated. Please edit it if I guessed wrong about what the problem was.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? There's propably a better solution, e.g. using a dictionary.

Answer (score 9):

In your code, "i" is a string, you need to do that:

```
aList = ["first", "second", "last"]
for i in aList:
    print getattr(self, i, None)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr

> getattr(object, name[, default])
>       Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
>   raised.

Answer (score 1):

You confuse `first` - a member of your class - with `"first"` - a string variable which happens to hold a content similar to your member.

Use `getattr` if you want to convert from the string to the real field